# Mocha faking second method call

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I have a method that has a nested If-Then statement.

The method under test calls a *second* method twice.

Something *almost* like this (very simplified):

```
module.exports = {
    method_under_test: async function () {
        let stat = await privateMethod();

        if (stat == 0) { return true; }
        else if (stat == 1) { return false; }
        else if (stat == 2) {
            doSomething();

            stat = await privateMethod();
            if (stat == 0) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
}

function privateMethod() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        doAsync((rep) => {
            if (rep) {
                if (rep === 'something') { resolve(0); }
                else { resolve(1); }
            } else {
                resolve(2);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Notice that if `stat == 2` then a process is executed and the private method is run a second time to make sure the process ran successfully.

**NOTE:** I cannot change the `doAsync` method in my private method.  All I can do is interpret the results.

So, my question is... I want to *fake* my `privateMethod` so that on the first call, it returns `2`, but on the second call it returns `1` and allows me to test the `else` portion of my nested If-Else.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you could probably mock `doAsync` and control its return value in order to influence the result of `privateMethod`? You say you can't modify it, but unless it's private you should be able to stub (replace) it somehow. In this way, you're simulating the same external changes you would expect to modify the actions taken. Downside is this is potentially brittle, but no moreso than any other solution involving mocks I think.

Comment: The thing is, I could probably mock or stub `doAsync` or `privateMethod`.  What I don't know how to do is say (in pseudo code) in my unit test: "first time privateMethod is called, return 2; on the second time privateMethod is called, return 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhh, i found it :)

sinon, as of version 1.8, has an [`onCall`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stuboncalln-added-in-v18) method.

Comment: here's a blog post in case someone stumbles on this and has a question: http://jdav.is/2019/01/29/using-sinonrewire-for-unit-testing-with-private-methods/